# RequestHeaderPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter class is not present in Spring Security 3.2.3 version

Tags: java, spring-security, java-8

I am trying to migrate my project Spring Security from 2.0.4 to 3.2.3 for java 8 up gradation. `RequestHeaderPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` class is present in spring-security-core-2.0.4 but not in either of spring-security-core-3.2.3 , spring-security-config-3.2.3 , spring-security-web-3.2.3.

can someone please tell me in which jar that class is present for Spring Security 3.2.3 version or any higher version.

Comment: It is called `RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter` not `RequestHeaderPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Deinum.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Deinum. Can you please give me the link where I can find these changes. I have to investigate for PreAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesAuthenticationDetails , AbstractPreAuthenticatedAuthenticationDetailsSource also. Thanks again..

Comment: THe Spring Security reference guide especially the upgrade guides.